# ESLint: What does it mean if a rule is fixable?

Tags: eslint, rule

According to [ESLint: Docs: Rules](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/),

> Some rules are fixable using the --fix command line flag.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Running the command `eslint --help`, tells us that the `--fix` command line flag "automatically fix[es] problems."

[ESLint: Docs: User Guide: Command Line Interface: `--fix`](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface.html#fix) provides more explanation:

> This option instructs ESLint to try to fix as many issues as possible.
>   The fixes are made to the actual files themselves and only the
>   remaining unfixed issues are output. Not all problems are fixable
>   using this flag, and the flag does not work in these situations:
>
> 1. This option throws an error when code is piped to ESLint.
> 2. This option has no effect on code that uses processors.